# Windows Media Player 12 can't read out CD Text data

Tags: windows-media-player, extension, audio-cd

I installed and enabled WMPCDText extension for Windows Media Player in hope it will allow for reading CD Text data from a CD. But it can't quite recognise any CD Text data and therefore it still shows up "Track #/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album" sort of thing.

I've created a CUE sheet for a single WAV file containing a mix of songs. That CUE sheet has CD Text compatible data (mostly disc and track titles and performers). If I open up the CUE sheet in ImgBurn as if I could burn it, and click to show metadata, it shows up the CD Text data perfectly. But Windows Media Player with the extension installed and enabled doesn't. How do I make it work for Media Player? Is there any other WMP extension that can do the same?

Comment: What's your version of Windows/WMPCDText? Which program did you use to burn the CD? Would it be possible to verify that the CD actually contains CD-Text? (by checking with another program that reads CD-Text or with a standalone CD player)

What happens when you load the CD in WMP's `Play` pane (on the right), right-click on one of the tracks, and select `Read CD-Text`?

Comment: Windows 10 Home, WMPCDText v1.14 - the Audio CD is actually virtual image written on my own. ImgBurn actually identified the image including all CD-Text data, all correct. But when I mount the CUE sheet as a virtual image by Daemon Tools (ImgBurn does not support virtual drives of course, for a reason) and play the mounted virtual CD, the WMOCDText extension is unable to read CD-Text data. If I force to read the data, it shows an error reading CD-Text data. Maybe Daemon Tools do not support CD-Text?

Comment: I can vaguely remember from my own experience that Daemon Tools don't support CD-Text. But to double-check, you'd better ask their support. Nonetheless, WMPCDText doesn't support virtual CD images, as it has only been tested with physical audio CDs.